# Reason for the error in ANOVA: models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset

Tags: anova, model, error, glmm

I have been running with this error for a long time and I have been failing to fix it. Does anyone have an idea?

````
  models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset```

MaggYN4 = glmer(AggYN ~ AGE + SocialFYN + SocialMYN + Oestrus + (1|ZOO) + (1|`MALE ID`) + (1|`FEMALE ID`), data=subset(Data_Okapi, Aggression<4), family = "binomial")

NullaggYN4 = glmer(AggYN ~ (1|ZOO) + (1|`MALE ID`) + (1|`FEMALE ID`), data=subset(Data_Okapi, Aggression<4), family = "binomial", na.action = na.exclude)

anova(MaggYN4, NullaggYN4)

summary(MaggYN4)
````